# Zero product property and Multiplicative Cancellation law for rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Basically, I'm trying to prove a property for rings:

Let $R$ be a ring.

Statement (1): For all $a, b$ in $R$, if $ab = 0$, then $a = 0$ or $b = 0$

Statement (2): For all $a, b, c$ in $R$, if $ab = ac$ and  $a \neq 0$, then $b = c$.

Prove that (1) is true IFF (2) is true.

I've proved the forward direction (1) => (2) pretty simply (I think):

> If for all $a, b$ in $R$, $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, then the same follows for any some $c$ in R. 
>       That is, $ac = 0$ implies $a = 0$ or $c = 0$. 
>       Then, if $ac = 0$ and $ab = 0$, we see that $ab$ = $ac$. If we assume that $a \neq 0$, then 
>       from statement (1) implication that $a = 0$ or $b = 0, a = 0$ or $c = 0$, we see that $b = 0$ and 
>       $c = 0$. So, $b = 0$ and $c = 0$ and we see that $b = c$.

Having trouble on the reverse statement (2) => (1). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that (2) is true. Suppose $ab = 0$ and $a \neq 0$. Then $ab = a\cdot 0$, so by property (2), we have $b = 0$, which shows (1) holds.

Comment: starting from (2), we have if ab = ac and a =/= 0, then b = c. 

If we take ab = 0 and assume c = 0, then b = 0 from (2).... I don't see where this is going, as c = 0 isn't one of the assumptions of the "if" of (1) 

(sorry im still confused)

Comment: @Ted: you want to prove that if $ab = 0$, then one of $a$ or $b$ is $0$. You're assuming (2), which states that for ANY $a, b,c \in R$ satisfying $ab = ac$ with $a \neq 0$, then $b = c$. So suppose $a \neq 0$, and $ab = 0$. We want to show that this implies $b = 0$. Since we have $ab = a\cdot 0$, then applying (2), we *must* have $b = 0$. This is what we wanted to show, so we're done.